# spacy custom tokenizer doesn't group words

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Using spacy,  I'm trying to merge three different tokens into one token.

for example two different tokens "bell" "peper" into one token "bell pepper" by the code below.(I don't think my code is a right approach though)

```
text='extra-virgin olive oil bell pepper Parmesan Cheese onion red bell pepper carrots cloves, beans fennel bulb parsnips vegetable broth broccoli florets macaroni Parmesan cheese'


import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.tokenizer.add_special_case('connection',
    [
        {   'pos': 'NOUN',
            'F': '-',
            'F': 'oil'},
        {
            'F':'bell',
            'F':'pepper'
        },
        {
            'F':'olive',
            'F':'oil'
        },
        {
            'F':'Parmesan',
            'F':'Cheese'
        }
    ])

doc= nlp(text)

doc[0]

extra
```

How do I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're trying to do here - the text "olive-oil" isn't in your example text? Also with the small english model the "olive" in "olive-oil" is an adjective.

Comment: @polm23 What I'm trying to do is reverse tokenization for olive oil and bell pepper etc. Because when I do   // nlp('extra-virgin olive oil onion red bell pepper carrots cloves, beans fennel bulb parsnips vegetable broth broccoli florets macaroni Parmesan cheese') //    each word is tokenized, which I don't want I want to have tokens 'olive oil' not two seperate tokens olive, oil how do i achieve this?

Comment: @polm23 I updated my question cause even I found my question is hard to follow. Thank you

Comment: OK, thanks, that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like what you want to do is merge some phrases, like "olive oil" or "bell pepper", into single tokens. This is usually not something you'd do with the tokenizer exceptions - those are generally more useful for splitting words or dealing with idiosyncratic punctuation. For example, you might want to tokenize "gimme" as "gim me" (so that "me" can be recognized) or to have "2km" and "2 km" both be two tokens.

In this case I would make a list of all the phrases you want to make into a single token and use the [EntityRuler](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler) to assign an entity label to them. This assumes you have a list of the things you want to merge.

If you don't have a list of things you want to make into phrases, given your example text, this is going to be hard because there's no general principle like part of speech patterns behind the merges you're making. spaCy models are trained on natural language text, while you seem to just have an unpunctuated list of ingredients, so the part of speech tagger isn't always going to work very well. For example, consider these sentences:

> I went to the store and bought olive oil bell peppers and cake mix.

This is not properly punctuated, but it's obviously a list. If it were properly punctuated, spaCy's `noun_chunks` would give you what you want.

The issue is that this is also a valid sentence:

> I made olive oil bell pepper pasta for dinner.

This is somewhat awkward but properly punctuated, and in this case "olive oil bell pepper" is a modifier of "pasta" and not a list of separate items, so it would correctly be a single noun chunk.